# Find all users who have more than N processes and echo them in shell

Tags: linux, shell, ksh, ps, array

I'm writing a script in ksh.  I need to find all users who have more than N processes and echo them in the shell.  N is read from ksh.

I know that I should use `ps -elf`, but how do I parse it, find users with >N processes, and create an array with them?  I'm having a little trouble with arrays in ksh. Maybe a simple solution can help me instead of having to to create an array. One person recommended that I use

```
ps -elf | awk '{a[$3]++;}END{for(i in a)if (a[i]>N)print i, a[i];}' N=3
```

but it doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should reduce the columns output by `ps` to the minimum, i.e. request only the username here - this simplifies further processing.

For example:

```
$ ps -eo user=
```

will print the owner of all the currently running processes (`=` suppresses the header).

An easy way to get the counts for each user:

```
$ ps -eo user= | sort | uniq -c
  1 dovecot
  1 messagebus
  1 mpd
  1 polkitd
  2 postfix
121 root
 27 me
```

You can then filter that as you wish:

```
$ ps -eo user= | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1 > 42 {print $2}'
root
```

With a limit in a variable:

```
$ N=42
$ ps -eo user= | sort | uniq -c | awk -v limit="$N" '$1 > limit {print $2}'
root
```

Comment: BEST WAY ! THX!!

Comment: +1 You can also sort the output by the numeric column descending by piping to `sort -nrk 1`

Comment: @l0b0, `sort -rn` will do the same as `sort -rnk1`, since `-n` ignores the leading blanks anyway.